# Ruby on rails : detect the date of downloaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, download

I'm working on a task that zip and download files with ruby on rails using rubyzip gem, I want to check the last date of download.
here is the method the do the job :

```
def zip_it
    report = Report.find( params[ :id ] ).decorate
    pdf_filename = report.decorate.attachment_pdf_filename
    binding.pry

    public_pdf    = ReportPdf.new current_company, report, []
    public_pdf.generate_pdf( report, "public.pdf" )

    internal_pdf    = ReportPdf.new current_company, report, [], "internal"
    internal_pdf.generate_pdf( report, "internal.pdf"  )

    zip_pdf( "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdf/reports/#{report.reference}" )

    send_file( "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdf/reports/#{report.reference}.zip"  )
    download_date = DateTime.current
    binding.pry
  end
```

when i check the download_date variable it return nil !

some help ! thanks

Comment: It's a variable I want to save on it the download time of the file

Comment: Have you included: `require 'date'`?

Comment: thanks @SaraTibbetts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `DateTime.current` to work as expected you need to require the library.

Add `require 'date'` to fix your issue.